# отправка письма на мейл python

Tags: python, django, email

Есть такой код на `python` для отправки `email`. Почему он работает, только если сделаешь кучу настроек в гугл аккаунте? Как сделать так чтобы на любой мейл отправлялось без прописывания пароля от мейла и тд? Спасибо

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail 
send_mail('Django mail', 'This e-mail was sent with Django.', 
'your_account@gmail.com', ['your_account@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Есть логи ошибок, прочее?

Comment: @ProtectchildrenofDonbas2014, ну с локалхоста не отправляется, просто не приходит на мейл. Вообще главный вопрос как сделать так, чтобы не прописывать пароль от мейла, вдруг кому-то другому захочу отправить, но его пароль не знаю же. Как это работет, обычно же с формы идет на мейл письмо на сайтах